# HiveContext query in PySpark returns only NULL values for a timestampType column that has some NULL values

Tags: null, timestamp, pyspark

I have three timestamp columns in a Hive table that I'm attempting to query using HiveContext through PySpark (PySpark 1.6.0, Hadoop 2.6.0, CDH 5.9.2). One of the columns has no null values, the other two have null values. Queries from PySpark return valid timestamp values from the column with no null values, but only null values from the other two.

Querying the timestamp columns with no transformation or case statement delivers only NULL results to the PySpark Dataframe for the columns that contain nulls.

I have tried the following case statements. In each, the values are correctly shown in Impala but not in the PySpark results, which shows the RDDs as '9999-12-31 00:00:00' for all values, not just the NULL values:

```
case when this_dttm is null then cast('9999-12-31 00:00:00' as string) else this_dttm end as this_date
case when this_dttm is not null then this_dttm else cast('9999-12-31 00:00:00' as string) end as this_date
case when unix_timestamp(this_dttm) > 0 then this_dttm else cast('9999-12-31 00:00:00' as timestamp) end as this_date
```

I've also tried a conversion from timestamp to string back to timestamp, but this renders all values as NULL in Hive

```
cast(concat(substr(cast(this_dttm as string),7,4),"-",substr(cast(this_dttm as string),1,2),"-",substr(cast(this_dttm as string),4,2)) as timestamp) as this_date
```

Any advice for handling timestampType columns with NULL values would be appreciated.

Comment: If it helps, the NULL values only appear when there is no match from a left join. For example, I'm joining a table with coupon data to a table with coupon redemption data, and there's no matching coupon_id in the redemption table because the coupon was never used, so my redemption_dttm column is null.

Comment: What datatype do you get when you print the table's schema: `.printSchema()`

Comment: .printSchema() shows that all three fields are timestamp and are nullable

Comment: Could you provide some sample data then